# How to enable Java 7 in the web browser, in windows 8.1

Tags: java, firefox, windows-8.1

I am using Windows 8.1, I have installed java 7 and enabled Java Content in browser using Java Control Panel.
[image]

But when I go to this link:
https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstallapplet.jsp  to test my java installation my Mozilla Firefox says that java is not installed or is disabled.
[image]

Whereas when I check from command prompt it tells Java 7 is installed.
[image]

Please help me enabling java in my browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your Add-Ons in Firefox.  It may tell you that Java is disabled for security reasons.